# Plot Large data

Tags: r, ggplot2, large-data

I have a large file that contains two column data X,Y. I have got a round 20 million records. I want to graph the file in ggplot or even in normal plot (scattered plot). I used to read the file in R by using read command and store the whole data in a data frame, however, with the current size R can't read the file. I managed to plot the data in gnuplot by using `every` command to reduce the size. But I'd like to graph the file with R.

How to read the large file and plot it. I think reading the file line by line will not help because I want to graph the values. I'm not aware of any command like `èvery` in R.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: have you looked at `?sample`

Comment: If you knew the limits of your x and y variables, you could use `scan` to read in smaller sections of data at a time. The first set could be used to start the `plot(x,y,xlim=c(), ylim=c()`, while sequential parts could be added with `lines(x,y)`. This could all be done within a device like `png()` so that you don't overload the window device.

Comment: This seems like a problem for the [`bigvis`](https://github.com/hadley/bigvis) package: 'tools for exploratory data analysis of large datasets (10-100 million obs)'

Comment: sampling is probably the best solution anyway, even if you could heroically find a way to plot without sampling. Millions of points cannot be graphed effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I haven't used sample in R, and general sampling. I would appreciate an example to illustrate the sampling !!

Comment: Sampling is easy in R. But you should actually sampling before to load data in a data frame. You need a way to fast read lines in your file and fast skip a casual number of them. Tinkering with scan as Mark has proposed could be a solution. Maybe could also be faster to preprocess the file with another language of your choice (Python? Perl?).